# Add passenger for flights booked with Wizz Discount club

Tags: air-travel, europe, bookings, hungary, wizz-air

How can I add a passenger in my flight booked with Wizz Discount club? I can’t find the option.

Answer (score 4):

Adding a passenger would mean you're *changing* your booking. It's likely that as a low-fare airline, Wizz does not permit bookings to be changed or added-to, or doesn't permit new bookings for someone (the person you want to add) who isn't a member of the Wizz Discount Club.

In other words, there may be no link because it can't be done, or can't be done without additional charges. You might [contact Wizz](http://wizzair.com/en-gb/information-and-services/contact/contact-us) to ask them.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to choose a ticket for 2 people right away, cause there-s no function to add a person afterwards. If you purchase a ticket for 2 adults, you will get the WDC price for both.